# options.data has multiple index elements in handlebars helper

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars template structured like this:

```
{{#each array}}
    some stuff
    {{#each array2}}
        some more stuff
        {{#customHelper}}{{/customHelper}}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Each array contains four items.

The handlebars helper looks like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('customHelper', function(options){
    console.log(options.data);
});
```

`options.data` contains the number of times (`index`) it's been through the `#each`. If there are multiple `#each`'s it returns the innermost one. However, I want the index of the outermost `#each`.

Logging `options.data` gives:

```
Object {index: 0, index: 0}
Object {index: 1, index: 0}
Object {index: 2, index: 0}
Object {index: 3, index: 0}
Object {index: 0, index: 1}
Object {index: 1, index: 1}
Object {index: 2, index: 1}
Object {index: 3, index: 1}
Object {index: 0, index: 2}
Object {index: 1, index: 2}
Object {index: 2, index: 2}
Object {index: 3, index: 2}
Object {index: 0, index: 3}
Object {index: 1, index: 3}
Object {index: 2, index: 3}
Object {index: 3, index: 3}
```

This shows that both indexes are there. The first index is the innermost `#each` and the second one is the outermost one. As far as I'm aware, it shouldn't even be possible to have two identical keys in a javascript object.

logging `options.data.index` gives the first `index`, not the second one.

Is it possible to access the second `index`, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
Deleting index:

```
delete options.data.index;
```

Will delete only the first one, so now

```
options.data.index
```

will return the index of the outer `#each`